# How to zip multiple files with similar filenames in C#

Tags: c#, file, process, zip

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to take a folder and zip each group of similar name. This 
would be names which are the same not the extension.

Here is a rough draft of code I put together:

```
//When it gets to the 3rd file it for some reason throws an exception
//System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\Temp\zipped\fileb.zip'.
//The funny thing is that I would figure it is trying to write this new filename why look for it
//This uses the Ionic.Zip.dll library 
string InputDir="C:\\Temp\\";
string OutputDir="C:\\Temp\\zipped\\";
string prevFilename="";
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(InputDir);//Will change this later
for (int x=0; x < myOtherList.Count;x++)
{
    string fullfilename = myOtherList[x];
    string[] fileDOTextension = fullfilename.Split('.');

    if ((fileDOTextension[0]!=prevFilename)&&(x!=0))
    {
        zip.Save(OutputDir+prevFilename+".zip");
        zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("name = *.*");
    }

    zip.AddFile(myOtherList[x]);
    prevFilename=fileDOTextension[0];
}
```

Comment: A FileNotFoundException is a FileNotFoundException. Re-check where the exception is generated from. Use the debugger to help.

Comment: Your split might not work cleanly.  What if the filename has a period in it, such as system.data.dll?  To get the filename without the extension, you should use Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension(filename)

Comment: It throws the exception at the line:
--> zip.Save(OutputDir+prevFilename+".zip")
which doesn't make sense because why would it look for a file it's trying to create. It should only look for items it added to it's queue.   
As far as the filename being split cleanly.  Hmm so far I've used that technique a few times and it looks like it's clean splits. I'm still thinking the dll is doing a search for some reason before the save. Not sure...

Comment: Another strange aspect of this code is that it did create the first zip file in my chosen directory correctly. So I still don't think it has to do with the filename.

Comment: Doesn't relate to the error, but you should note that this is not saving the last zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I am betting it is this line:

```
zip.AddFile(myOtherList[x]);
```

At this point, it has to find the zip file in question. The fact you are reusing the exact same object makes this harder to debug, so I would consider moving into its own routine and feeding the name of the zip and the file paths to zip in a single zip file to the routine. You then create a new zip and add files rather than reuse the same zip object.

Comment: It don't think it seems to be having a problem with that line. It is able to find the file to add. It's just that it throws the exception on the creation of the 2nd zip file.

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond to the 2nd part of your comment. I'm going to have to think a bit to figure out how to do what you're saying.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Linq (ie Framework 3.5 or later), you could do something like the following

This uses Linq to group the files by the fileName (without the extension). Once in this format, it makes it easier to iterate through them.

```
string InputDir="C:\\Temp\\";
string OutputDir="C:\\Temp\\zipped\\";

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(InputDir);//Will change this later
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(InputDir);
var filenames = di.GetFiles().ToList();

var zipFiles = 
    (
    from r in filenames 
    group r by System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r.Name) into results
    select new { results.Key , Filenames = (from r in results select r.FullName) } 
    );


foreach(var r in zipFiles)
{
    string zipFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(OutputDir , r.Key + ".zip");
    Console.WriteLine("Creating Zip file " + zipFileName);

    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

    foreach(var filename in r.Filenames)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("     Adding File " + filename);
        zip.AddFile(filename);
    }
    zip.Save(zipFileName);
}
```

Haven't tested this, and also I don't know how Ionic handles the case where the zip file already exists.

Comment: I only have SharpDevelop at the moment which I don't think I can get LINQ running on it. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Does the output directory exist?  If I remember correctly, not finding the directory also throws a `FileNotFoundException` and creating a file will not automatically create the directory path, it needs to be created before hand.

Comment: Yes the output directory is created already. It did create the first file smoothly.

Comment: I'm wondering if it has something to do with reinitializing the Zip object to clear everything out of it to start with new values to the add method.  Still scratching my head.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the Ionic.Zip.dll library can't dispose of itself correctly.  Not sure I'm using the right term.   After trying so many other ideas I think to myself how about if I create the unique list differently.   Voila my solution is not using LINQ cause I can't find it for SharpDevelop but instead some old code:

```
//Create a new list to store filenames (minus extension)   
List<String> myOtherList =  new List<String>();

foreach (String strCol in listBox1.Items) 
    myOtherList.Add(strCol.Split('.')[0]);

//Create a new list to store UNIQUE filenames (minus extension)
List<string> uniques = new List<string>();

foreach (string item in myOtherList)
    if (!uniques.Contains(item)) uniques.Add(item);

//Set some static values for the test     
string InputDir="C:\\Temp\\";
string OutputDir="C:\\Temp\\zipped\\";

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(InputDir);

//Create a new object instances for each new zip file
for (int x=0; x < uniques.Count;x++)
{
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile();

    zip.AddSelectedFiles(uniques[x]+".*");
    zip.Save(OutputDir+uniques[x]+".zip");//uses OutputDir+
    zip.RemoveSelectedEntries("name = *.*");
}
```